# Is casting an object instance to a byte pointer the same as type punning?

Tags: c++, pointers, types, type-punning

I've been talking about type punning with my roommate and we were disagreeing on whether or not taking an object and assigning it's reference to a byte pointer to treat it as a byte array in order to pass it to a system call, was the same as type punning or not? I had just learned about this term today and still wasn't exactly sure what it covered as I have probably done things that would be considered 'type punning' in the past but was unaware of the fact? I would just like some clarification on what is and isn't considered type-punning

Comment: It is not type punning. Any object may be accessed through a character type pointer. The C++ standard in this regard originated from the C standard, e.g. [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6) . The C++ standard had different wording, but is the same for char types.

Comment: C++ citation and standard reference within the discussion on [What is the Strict Aliasing Rule and Why do we care?](https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8)

Comment: I'd argue it's still _type punning_, because you're still treating an object of one type as another unrelated type without doing any sort of conversion. But it _is_ well defined behavior because casting to a `char*` and reading underlying bytes is explicitly allowed without breaking strict aliasing.

Comment: @parktomatomi punning to a character-type is explicitly allowed - [C++17 Standard - 7.2.1 Value Category (p11)](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11)  (7.2.1-11.3 specifically)